# Database type = Data Source Name?

Tags: php, database, content-management-system

I'm pretty new to PHP and programming in general, which is fairly straightforward and makes a good amount of sense so far. Currently I'm volunteering building small websites in order to familiarize myself with PHP. My last project took me a few weeks to develop, however, towards the end I realized I was completely ill informed. The server I have to transfer the files I've been working to does not support PHP! >:o

As frustrated as I am, instead of throwing in the towel and leaving my patron empty handed or telling them to have php installed, I'm trying to take this as an opportunity to learn basics of visual studio and ASP (which, with all the tools and plugins seems to be convoluted and confusing to me)

The hosting plan is I'm working with is the cheapest one (personal) found here
http://www.cybersharks.net/index.php?p=web_hosting_plans

So instead of building something from scratch like I did with the PHP, I'm looking for a small ASP CMS, (for a small forum, user login, admin capabilities) that I can quickly implement and stylize.

What I mostly dont understand is the database type (Data Source Name). Is this the ASP equivalent to mysql? To me, it seems to me most of the ASP CMS's are using MYSQL or MSSQL either way. (I dont see anything regarding Data Source Name in Visual Studio, upon further research it looks as if it's more of a protocol to accessing a database if anything).

So with the ASP and Data Source Name as my database, what are some (preferably open source) cms solutions I could use and implement quickly.

Sorry if this seems like a bad question, but I really could use some help on this one. I'm flat out befuddled.

Comment: @luckycypher: Please fix the title to cover the **actual** question, not your personal background.  The title doesn't help us decide if we can answer the actual question.  Apparently, "What I mostly dont understand is the database type (Data Source Name)" is your real question.  Please fix the title (and the question) to emphasize this.

Comment: Data Source is typically your database server/instance name.  See http://www.connectionstrings.com/ for examples of different connection strings.  http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008 is an example of a sql 2008 database.

Comment: @benjynito: Please post your answer as an actual answer.

Comment: Of course it can be good for you to learn ASP.NET, but why not upgrade the hosting plan for $5/m to include PHP. Even though you are a volounter, your time has some value. Maybe you could pay the $5/m ... ?

Comment: @Lott, I was hoping implying that I was a beginner would prompt someone to answer thoroughly. What do you think would be an appropriate title?

Comment: @Erik, Thanks for the suggestion but as a student, I'm already enough in debt as it is :/

Comment: @Lott I didn't feel I answered the question, was just trying to provide help for a piece of it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into dotNetNuke?

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/

Comment: That's actually the first one I looked at and started installing on my localhost. I just got confused when I saw `SQL Server 2005/2008 (Express) File SQL Server 2005/2008 Database` and Data Source Name as the database in the hosting. Ill take another look

Answer (score 2):

Since it was requested, my note is now a *partial* answer.  See others for CMS, which I can't recommend.

Data Source is typically your database server/instance name. See [connectionstrings](http://connectionstrings.com).com for examples of different connection strings. connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008 is an example of a sql 2008 database.